# hdfs put fails from laptop to remote hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, unknown-host, datanode

I have my hadoop cluster set up on a different network. Because of this, `hdfs put` is failing when I run it from my laptop.

Is there a port I should forward or something to access the datanodes remotely? I see it's using the local ip address in the error message.

Here is the command: `hdfs dfs -put ~/Documents/reddit-streaming/redditStreaming/target/redditStreaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar hdfs://mydns.asuscomm.com:8021/user/me/jars/`

and here is the error message:

```
2021-10-14 18:04:55,704 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073742036_1212
java.net.UnknownHostException
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1711)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
2021-10-14 18:04:55,708 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-668799564-192.168.50.7-1633461871664:blk_1073742036_1212
2021-10-14 18:04:55,752 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.50.31:9866,DS-60974173-31d6-4dcb-a2ba-05ab6431db66,DISK]
2021-10-14 18:05:00,801 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Exception in createBlockOutputStream blk_1073742037_1213
java.net.UnknownHostException
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createSocketForPipeline(DataStreamer.java:253)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1757)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1711)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
2021-10-14 18:05:00,801 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Abandoning BP-668799564-192.168.50.7-1633461871664:blk_1073742037_1213
2021-10-14 18:05:00,833 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.50.19:9866,DS-aeaca5a1-562c-4f35-b2fb-6f0b51c5f695,DISK]
2021-10-14 18:05:00,869 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /user/me/jars/redditStreaming-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar._COPYING_ could only be written to 0 of the 1 minReplication nodes. There are 2 datanode(s) running and 2 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:2329)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:294)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2942)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:915)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:593)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:568)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:552)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1093)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:1035)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:963)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2966)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1573)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1519)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1416)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:530)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.addBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1084)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DataStreamer.java:1898)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DataStreamer.java:1700)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer.run(DataStreamer.java:707)
```

---

I have this property in my `hdfs-site.xml` file on my laptop:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>true</value>
</property>
```

I can also see in the UI that both datanodes are running.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've forwarded the namenode port (`8021`) since it can see that 2 datanodes exist?

Yes, the datanodes have their own ports that need to be available to the client for data to actually be written

Check the value for `dfs.datanode.address` and make sure you can establish a connection to the port listed there for each datanode.

If you look at the error, you can see this is `9866`

> Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[192.168.50.31:**9866**

And also, IIUC, the `use.datanode.hostname` config needs to actually be in the cluster, not your local laptop config, for the protocol to return the hostnames rather than the IPs

There is also an HTTP Port you can open if you want to see each Datanode's web-portal (should be available to be accessed from the Namenode UI as well)

---

The alternative, more secure / less exposed, option is to establish an edge-node between the networks that you can only SSH to & SFTP files into (assuming you don't otherwise have a shared fileserver), then run your `hdfs` commands from there. You can setup a SOCKS proxy if you needed to access a Web UI in that network

To re-iterate, you should **not** expose a Hadoop cluster without Kerberos & TLS over dynamic DNS through any internet-facing router

Comment: thanks for all the advice! I'm definitely doing things in an insecure way right now so I should probably spend some time cleaning that up. but I see what you're saying and have my master node that I can ssh into and use for hdfs access